# Executing BuildScript on local server through Jenkins using SSH server

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh

I've configured a job under Jenkins for building the application automatically. due to some restrictions and access problem i need to build my application on my own server (Linux) instead of building it over Jenkins server.In order to do that I've written a BuildScript which relies in my server and when this file is executed it initiates the build process and does all the required operations to be done and creates the war file to be deployed.
I want to invoke that file(Build Script) from Jenkins so that build will be initiated on my server through Jenkins. I'm trying to do this using the **Send files or execute commands over SSH before the build starts** under the build environment of my job but somehow I'm getting the result.

Does anyone has any idea regarding this?. If you have then plz share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. Create a node in jenkins for your local linux server. (If note
   already created)
2. In Jenkins job configuration use this node under "Restrict where this project can be run"
3. Under "Build" section use Execute Shell from Add build step dropdown.

Now every command or script mentioned under Execute Shell will be run on configured node (which is your own local server). You can use jenkins workspace if you want using ${WORKSPACE} variable.

Thanks

Comment: Actually what I was thinking about is to use the options enlisted inside the Build Environment **Execute Shell Script on remote host using SSH** from there I'll provide my machine under SSH site and write the command in pre build Script section which is to be executed on the Linux server.
Please give me your opinion on this.